# What is the meaning of sqlType in registerOutParameter of jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-types

I'm using jdbc CallableStatement to execute procedures in MySQL database. While writing unit tests I have encountered strange behaviour regarding registerOutParameter method.

Used SQL procedures

```
PROCEDURE TEST_DOUBLE( OUT val DOUBLE ) BEGIN SET val = 2.5; END
PROCEDURE TEST_TEXT( OUT val TEXT ) BEGIN SET val = 'test'; END
```

Tests

```
statement = connection.prepareCall( "CALL TEST_DOUBLE(?)" );
statement.registerOutParameter( "val" , java.sql.Types.INTEGER );
statement.execute();
statement.getInt( "val" ); //Integer 2
statement.getDouble( "val" ); //Double 2.5
statement.getString( "val" ); //String "2.5"

statement = connection.prepareCall( "CALL TEST_TEXT(?)" );
statement.registerOutParameter( "val" , java.sql.Types.INTEGER );
statement.execute();
statement.getInt( "val" ); //Invalid value for getInt
statement.getDouble( "val" ); //Invalid value for getDouble
statement.getString( "val" ); //String "test"

statement = connection.prepareCall( "CALL TEST_TEXT(?)" );
statement.registerOutParameter( "val" , 0 );
statement.execute();
statement.getInt( "val" ); //Invalid value for getInt
statement.getDouble( "val" ); //Invalid value for getDouble
statement.getString( "val" ); //String "test"
```

and so on...

My point is - values java.sql.Types.* passed to registerOutParameter seem to do nothing... Regardless of what sql type I pass, everything depends on calling proper getter method and the real value returned by the database.

Can I just everywhere pass 0 and it will work properly anyway? 
Why is this parameter passed then? 
Or maybe is this database related, and for other databases it is meaningfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that this parameter is database-related.  Oracle certainly pays attention to it:

```
statement = connection.prepareCall("CALL_TEST_NUMBER(?)");
statement.registerOutParameter("val", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
statement.execute();
statement.getInt("val");       // 2
statement.getDouble("val");    // 2.5
statement.getString("val");    // "2.5"

statement = connection.prepareCall("CALL TEST_TEXT(?)");
statement.registerOutParameter("val", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
statement.execute();   //  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Answer (score 0):

This method expects an integer in this pararameter as you can see in jdbc [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int%29). The field you use as a constant (java.sql.Types.INTEGER) is a int (public static final int INTEGER) as all the rest of constant values in [java.sql.Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#INTEGER), and thats why your code works when you put 0 (maybe 0 value is the same than java.sql.Types.INTEGER or another Number type). 
This parameter tells the driver which type you expect to read for this output value.

When you try to use another java.sql.Type (i.e. java.sql.Type.ARRAY) you probablly get a classCast or conversion error because the jdbc driver does not know how to conver the value returned from de callableStatement (a number) to the type you wanted (an array).

Comment: I have just tested that, and it turned out not to be true.
Procedure has OUT val INT
I have used registerOutParam( "val" , java.sql.Types.ARRAY )
If only I use getInt( "val" ) code works without any problems, just as if I passed java.sql.Types.INTEGER or 0

Comment: Um, thats weird. The behaviour of this method should be what is described in jdbc API, as is explainted in documentation. Maybe the driver you are using has a different behaviour? Do you have soma driver specific API javadoc?